# Multiple string replaces in one line

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I have a sql statement and for debugging I want to print it. The statement contains placeholders and I want to fill the placeholders in one instruction line before I print. Is this valid or UB?

```
std::string query("SELECT A, B FROM C WHERE D = ? and E = ?;");
std::cout << query.replace(query.find("?"), 1, "123").replace(query.find("?"), 1, "234") << std::endl;
```

Is the order of the instructions

1. Find position of first question mark
2. Replace first string in query
3. Find position of second question mark after first replacement
4. Replace second string in query

guaranteed or is it possible that both `find` operations can be called before both `replace` operations like

1. Find position of first question mark
2. Find position of second question mark before first replacement
3. Replace first string in query
4. Replace second string in query

I'm asking because:

> Order of evaluation of the operands of almost all C++ operators
>   (including the order of evaluation of function arguments in a
>   function-call expression and the order of evaluation of the
>   subexpressions within any expression) is unspecified. The compiler can
>   evaluate operands in any order, and may choose another order when the
>   same expression is evaluated again.

EDIT: 
It's not possible to use third party dependencies in this project.

Comment: Would wrapping it in lambda still qualify as one liner? `std::cout << [&] { query.replace(query.find("?"), 1, "123"); query.replace(query.find("?"), 1, "234"); return query; }() << std::endl;`

Comment: @KillzoneKid: The question is less to find a one liner that works but more to understand if this would be valid or UB and to avoid future errors. But I like the idea of using lambdas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find anything in the rules of order of evaluation that strictly specifies the ordering of the function arguments of chained functions. That is to say that in your case you can know that:

1. The first `replace` is sequenced before the second one, because the second one operates on its return value
2. Each `find` call is sequenced before the `replace` that uses its return value as an argument

But what you want is for the first `replace` to be sequenced before the second `find` and there is no such guarantee. For reference, see the rules [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Answer (score 3):

In `query.replace(query.find("?"), 1, "123").replace(query.find("?"), 1, "234")`

`query.find("?")` is un-sequenced from each other.
so result is unpredictable between possible sequences.

Comment: un-sequenced or indeterminately-sequenced?

Comment: @Deduplicator: Might vary from compiler, and even from different run.

Comment: No. Which one it is is defined by the standard. The former is less constrained than the latter, and I think it's the latter. Both allow for variation from one run/compiler/version to the next though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`boost::algorithm::replace_first`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/replace_first.html) multiple times:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/replace.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string query("SELECT A, B FROM C WHERE D = ? and E = ?;");
    for(auto replacement : {"123", "1"})
        boost::algorithm::replace_first(query, "?", replacement);
    std::cout << query << '\n';
}
```

Note that this simple string replacement won't work for replacement strings that need quoting.

Comment: Isn't `boost` a third-party dependency?

Comment: It is a third party dependency and we can't use boost because we use a library that dynamically links boost and we do not know the version and build flags.

Comment: @ThomasSablik `boost::algorithm::replace_first` is implemented in the headers, no linking of boost shared/static libs is required. Still though, that may cause an ODR violation with that unknown boost version you dynamically load.